# How to utilize the Microsoft Azure Free Credits (200$) When we weren't known which regions are supported and having capacity to deploy our resources?

Tags: azure, azureportal, azure-cost-calculation, azure-free-services

Azure VM for Free Trail Subscription is available in East US, West US 2, Southeast Asia, West Europe, and Central US.
Whatever the location I select, it shows the same message called "This size is currently unavailable in (any above location) for this subscription. NotAvailableForSubscripton"
".

Even for the Function Apps deployment, tried with several regions.

After speaking in Azure Chat Support, they said capacity is less in regions of Free Trail users.
But those regions are not known by users. Finally, it is deployed successfully in North Europe. But most of the services are not able to deploy the nearby locations like South India, West India, West US, East US, Central US, West US2, East US2, etc.

In this case, when we're not known which region is free to deploy our resources during the free trial, how do we utilize the Azure free Credits?

[image: AzureVMCreatePage]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a customer service-related question. Contact MS directly for questions related to their services and your account. Questions related to code are acceptable here, other topics are not. For more information, see the [help] and [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to SadiqhAhmed-MSFT, as this question is addressed in the [Microsoft Q&A Site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/806516/how-to-utilize-the-microsoft-azure-free-credits-20.html). Posting here to help other community members.

> I understand your concern about not being able to spin up VM in the mentioned regions (*East US, West US 2, Southeast Asia, West Europe, and Central US*) using your Azure free trial account.

**FYI: Azure is available in 140+ countries/region.**

> However, the issue you are experiencing is because not all regions are enabled by default for Azure free trial account due to region constrains or capacity constraints.

> Region constrains: Those regions which are high in demand and are available only on request basis/business requirement (Justification). These regions are enabled for Azure free trial account

> Capacity constrains: These regions again are high in demand and are not available due to capacity issues. but can be enabled through support.

> For your situation, I recommend you contact Azure subscription management team for region enablement by raising a support request. The ticket enables you to work closely with the support engineers and get a quick resolution to your issue.

> Here is the link -  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request  to create a support case.

> FYI: Azure Billing and Subscription Management support is included in the Basic Support Plan without any charge.
> https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/plans/